Which is the subject here?
We know that subject of an Imperative Sentence (You) remains understood.
For example,

"Look at the cuckoo in that tree."
Here, subject of the intransitive verb 'Look' is "You", which is understood here.
And "the cuckoo" is the object of the preposition 'at'.
But I have found on the internet that in that given example, the subject is "the cuckoo". How is it possible? Please clarify it grammatically.


It's not possible. The subject is undoubtedly "you" in this imperative clause.

"I have found on the internet" Where?

Is the indented bit a quotation? If so, from where?
